# ASP.NET MVC + Selenium resize windows error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, selenium

I have a problem with resizing selenium windows, I am try to create screenshot of web site and use the selenium for this. I am use the following code part:

```
public void CreateScreenshot ()
{
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
var js = webDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

string temWindowName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

js.ExecuteScript(String.Format("window.open('{0}', '{1}', 'width={2},height={3}')", "http://www.google.com", temWindowName, 1920, 680));
webDriver.Close();
webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(temWindowName);

js = webDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript(String.Format("window.resizeTo({0},{1});", 1920, 860));
js.ExecuteScript(String.Format("window.moveTo(0,0)"));

Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile(string.Format("c:/temp.png", args[0]), ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

When I try run this code part locally without IIS all works fine, when app run on IIS I can't get a width of screenshot more that 1028px.

Anyone know why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to launch selenium from IIS hosted application?
If so then I assume you're experiencing same issue as I do which I just reported - [Issue 4174](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4174)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I have found the way how to fix this issue. I just created a windows app wrapper with windows sockets to communicate with it that starts on windows startup. This approach fixed all troubles and I can set any window size I want. But when you start the selenium process as a child process of IIS or when you try to create a windows service wrapper for selenium you will have the problem with window resizing.

Comment: Hi. Well I've actually switched to RemoteWebDriver and having selenium server running on a desktop session which works fine, but I'd still like to avoid having the desktop session at all.